# i am not able to install platfomio-ide-terminal in ATOM

Tags: python, atom-editor

Installing “platformio-ide-terminal@2.10.0” failed.Hide output…

> node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-120327-4684-1n45eei.2yxd\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch
>   prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js

C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-120327-4684-1n45eei.2yxd\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.45.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.45.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )

prebuild-install WARN install unexpected end of file
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.45.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:492:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.45.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:517:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.45.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.45.0\resources\app\apm\bin\node.exe" "C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.45.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-120327-4684-1n45eei.2yxd\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch
gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-120327-4684-1n45eei.2yxd\package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-120327-4684-1n45eei.2yxd No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-120327-4684-1n45eei.2yxd No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-120327-4684-1n45eei.2yxd No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-120327-4684-1n45eei.2yxd No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install: `prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\saqib.atom.apm_logs\2020-04-27T04_37_34_189Z-debug.log

Comment: It would help a lot if you wrap your error log into a code block, by adding triple-backticks (```) at the start and end of it. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help how to format things properly.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your atom to default setting by deleting .atom directory in your /username folder. Then try to install.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly reads:

```
Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\saqib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

You need to install Python 3.8 - or point the `PYTHON` environmental variable to where it resides.

Answer (score -1):

I have had similar problem befor..

SOLUTION: Just uninstall the current version of your Atom and Install the latest Version..then try re-install the plugin (platformio-ide-terminal) this should work